# Reducer not fetching the initial state in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a 'to do list' application in react and redux.
I've built several reducers in the course of development such as 'buckets', 'todos' etc.
The 'buckets' reducer seems to pick up the initialState of the app just fine while the other reducers don't (they console empty arrays).
I can't figure out why.

My index.js file

```
import todoApp from './reducers/index.js';
import App from './components/App';
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

const initialState = {
    buckets: [
        {   
            name: 'Test Bucket',
            id: 0,
            visibilityFilter: "SHOW_ALL",
            todos: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    text: "This is a test",
                    completed: true
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    text: "Random entry",
                    completed: true
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    text: 'Another random entry',
                    completed: false
                }
            ]
        },
        {   
            name: 'Default',
            id: 1,
            visibilityFilter: "SHOW_ALL",
            todos: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    text: "Alpha Beta Gamma",
                    completed: true
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    text: "Lorem Ipsum",
                    completed: true
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    text: 'Something Something',
                    completed: false
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
};

let store = createStore(todoApp, initialState);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

My Reducers file

```
import { VisibilityFilters } from '../actions/index.js';
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

function buckets(state = [], action) {
  console.log('buckets',state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_BUCKET': {
      return [...state, {
        name: action.text,
        id: action.id,
        visibilityFilter: "SHOW_ALL",
        todos: []
      }];
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

function todos(state = [], action) {
  console.log('todos',state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO': {
      return [...state, {
        text: action.text,
        completed: false,
        id: action.id
      }];
    }

    case 'TOGGLE_TODO': {
      return state.map((todo, id) => {
        if (id === action.id) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: !todo.completed
          });
        }

        return todo;
      });
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

function visibilityFilter(state = VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL, action) {
  console.log('visibilityFilter',state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER': {
      return action.filter;
    }

    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}

let todoApp = combineReducers({
  visibilityFilter,
  todos,
  buckets
});

export default todoApp;
```

My github repo: https://github.com/iamrkcheers/ToDoList

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: you need to add `react-redux`, `redux`, and `react-router-dom` to your package.json, otherwise the app won't install the necessary dependencies. Other than that, your code seems to be correct. The state is being initialized, I checked.

Comment: You can check by going into BucketListContainer and adding state to the return of mapStateToProps, and then console.logging it in BucketList. The printed out state is the one you initialized in the reducers plus the one you preloaded in createStore.

Comment: A few extra tips: don't put all your reducers in one file, and you should probably put that preloadedState in the reducer file for BucketList, and pass it as default parameter value to the BucketList reducer.

Comment: @evianpring 'buckets' reducer is working fine. Its the 'todos' reducer that is not fetching the initial state.

Comment: Each reducer only gets slice of the state not the entire state which you seem to be expecting. Code behavior is correct. You are expecting todos and visibilityFilter to be at the top level but you have it inside individual bucket array.

Comment: @Rikin how can I access individual bucket inside the todos reducer ?